# Phpmailer SMTP 500 Error

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I am getting error message when using phpmailer smtp function.  I am using php5 and below is the code I used.

```
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
    $mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.com';
    $mail->Port = 21; 
    $mail->Username = xxx;  
    $mail->Password = xxx;           
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $firstname . " " . $lastname);
    $mail->AddAddress($contact);

    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->Body     = $message;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Send();

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "email_has_not_been_sent <br><br>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
$IsSent = 0;
exit;
}
```

here are the error messages.

```
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 500 EHLO not understood 
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 500 HELO not understood 
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 500 AUTH not understood 
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 500 RSET not understood 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 500   MAIL not understood
```

Answer (score 1):

your code looks ok, but I think you're using a port more commonly used for FTP... [25 and 587 are more commonly used as SMTP ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)

Some basic telneting should tell you what's going on:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

then enter the command `EHLO` and you will see the welcome message of the gmail SMTP server.

Now try that on your server and you'll see what you get

Then try the same for more common SMTP ports: **25** and **587** and you should see the difference.